# Woocommerce Subscriptions changing to "on hold" instead of renewing

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

Having a problem with my subscriptions being placed on hold each month instead of renewing automatically. Has anybody had this problem or have a solution?

Comment: It's an annoying issue. I believe the plugin creators deliberately make it difficult to know what's going on with basic logging so that you have to pay them for support. Shopify has an excellent subscription plugin.

Answer (score 2):

This will happen when you're using a payment method that doesn't support recurring payments (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/payment-gateways/ - go here to check supported gateways). What is happening is it's going into manual mode. You might want to check your Subscriptions settings and make sure automatic subscriptions isn't turned off too (WooCommerce > Settings > Subscriptions and "Turn off automatic payments" is unchecked). With manual payments, the order is placed on hold and the user has to go into their account and the subscription area and pay to renew.